# Nopcommerce absolute url

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

It's possible change default `MapLocalizedRoute` to display absolute url in page source ?
Currently in nopcommerce 3.50 in page source is:

```
<a href="/register">register<a/>
```

but i try change to:

```
<a href="mydomain.com/register">register<a/>
```

It's possible ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Try using @Url.Content("....